# paste values if cells match

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

In the previous post you guys helped me to find out a solution in order to copy-paste cells.

By now I've got a slight different problem.

Here is it; I've got 2 different sheets;

- `worksheets("Food")`
- `Worksheets("Numbers")`

In `worksheets("Food")`, I've got the following board;

```
| Fruits            | Vegetables    |
| --------          | --------------|
| Banana            | Carrots       |
| Peach             | Spinachs      |
| Pineapple         | Cauliflowers  |
```

In `worksheets("Numbers")`, I've got this;

```
| Fruits        | Numbers   |
| --------      | --------- |
| Banana        | 9         |
| Apple         | 2         |
| Orange        | 3         |
| Peach         | 7         |
| Pineapple     | 5         |
```

I'd like to search for each fruits from `worksheets("Food")` if they do exist in `worksheets("Numbers")`. If yes, then automatically insert a new column in `worksheets("Food")` between column Fruits and Vegetables named "Numbers".
After, picked up numbers beside each found fruits in `worksheets("Numbers")` and paste it in `worksheets("Food")` beside the matching fruit in the new created column.

Like this;

```
| Fruits     |*Numbers*      |Vegetables
| --------   |-------------- |------------
| Banana     |**9**          |Carrots
| Peach      |**7**          |Spinachs
| Pineapple  |**5**          |Cauliflowers
```

I've been trying to run a code doing this process but as I run it nothing happens ( no error occurs neither)...
Here is it;

```
Sub Add_Fruits_Numbers()

Dim lastlineFood As Long
Dim lastlineRef As Long
Dim j, i, compteur As Integer
Dim x As Long, rng As range

lastlineRef = Worksheets("Numbers").range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For j = 1 To lastlineRef
    lastlineFood = Worksheets("Food").range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    
        For i = 1 To lastlineFood
        If range("A" & i).Value = Worksheets("Numbers").range("A" & j).Value Then
        
            Set rng = Worksheets("Numbers").range("A1", range("A1").End(xlToRight))
                For Each cell In rng
                    If cell.Value = "Fruits" Then
                        cell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
                    End If
                Next cell
            
        
            Worksheets("Food").range("A" & i).Offset(, 1).Value = Worksheets("Numbers").range("A" & j).Offset(, 1)
        End If
        Next i
        


Next j
End Sub
```

I'd heavily appreciate your help once again, thank you !

Comment: Still alive? Do you really need help, or only like asking questions...?

Comment: Hey! Still alive!
Got an aswer bellow, and it worked well! thank you again !
(sorry tobe late tho ! ) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problems. It should raise an error on the line

```
 Set rng = Worksheets("Numbers").range("A1", range("A1").End(xlToRight))
```

if the active sheet is not "Numbers". `range("A1").End(xlToRight)` refers the active sheet. The correct code should be:

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Numbers").range("A1", Worksheets("Numbers").range("A1").End(xlToRight))
```

Then, your code inserts a column in the "Numbers" sheet.
You should use `Range("B" & i).EntireColumn.Insert` instead of `cell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)`. `cell` belongs to the range in "Numbers" sheet.

The code logic is wrong. The above sequence must be run only once. Otherwise it will insert a column for each match. "Fruits" will be there of each iteration.

Then everything is messed up and debugging more has no sense, no offence...

It is easier to show you a simpler/faster code, doing what (I understood) you want.

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub bringFruitsNo()
  Dim shF As Worksheet, shN As Worksheet, lastRF As Long, lastRN As Long
  Dim arrF, rngN As Range, mtch, i As Long, boolOK
  
  Set shF = Sheets("Food")
  Set shN = Sheets("Numbers")
  lastRF = shF.Range("A" & shF.rows.count).End(xlUp).row     'last row
  lastRN = shN.Range("A" & shN.rows.count).End(xlUp).row   'last row
  If shF.Range("B1").value = "Numbers" Then boolOK = True 'check if the column has already been inserted in a previous run
  arrF = shF.Range("A2:A" & lastRF).value 'put the first column in an array (for a faster iteration)
  Set rngN = shN.Range("A2:A" & lastRN) 'set the range where to search for the fruit existence
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrF)             'iterate between the array elements:
    mtch = Application.match(arrF(i, 1), rngN, 0) 'if the fruit has bee found:
    If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
        'insert the new necessary column and mark the inserting event changing the boolean variable value
        If Not boolOK Then shF.Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert: shF.Range("B1").value = "Numbers": boolOK = True
        shF.Range("B" & i + 1) = shN.Range("B" & mtch + 1).value  'Place the number in the new column
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

But, I think you maybe will need to use this code **after the column has been inserted**, and the code is checking if between "Fruits" and "Vegetables" a column named "Numbers" exists...

If not necessary, and always the code must insert a column between the first and the third column, that line can be deleted.

Comment: @Mido88 Didn't the above code answer your question? Did you test the code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: It worked really good, thank you !! ( sorry to be late!) :))